# What is happening to my data when i pass it through with @input

Tags: angular

I have set up a basic example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-input-pass-data

In the main app component i define data and fill a dropdown with it. I now pass this to another component and suddenly it does not see the data correctly anymore.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way to pass data in input:

```
<app-user [departmentItems]="departmentItems"></app-user>
```

Comment: Thanks I know it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way to pass your variable to other component:

`<app-user [departmentItems]="departmentItems"></app-user>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<app-user [departmentItems]="departmentItems"></app-user>
```

if you use `departmentItems` without `[]` you'll pass the value as string and not as an object...